# How to loop over row values in a two column data frame in R?

Tags: r, loops, apply

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
mydata <- data.frame(name = c("Rick", "Dan", "Michelle", "Ryan", "Gary"),
                     id = c (1:5))
```

I want to use the loop over the row and pull out the name and id variables for each. This is used to export a GTiff file. The important part is looping over each value. I've shown below how I could do it one by one using the `paste` functions to import the names as strings where necessary. In this case I would have 5 geotiff files, one for each name.

```
head(mydata)

x <- paste(mydata[1, 1])
x
y <- paste0(x, ".asc")
y
z <- paste(mydata[1, 2])
z

species_raster <- raster(y)

m <- c(0, as.numeric(z), 0, as.numeric(z), 1, 1)
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
rc <- reclassify(species_raster, rclmat)
plot(rc)
writeRaster(rc,
            filename = x,
            format = "GTiff",
            overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get a list of your pasted filenames with this

```
outputnames <- lapply(mydata[,1], paste0, ".asc")

#OR

outputnames <- lapply(mydata$name, paste0, ".asc")
```

These can later be used in another apply function or be referenced in a loop like so

```
for(i in mydata){
  writeRaster(rc,
              filename = i,
              format = "GTiff",
              overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

another alternative of referencing your dataframe in a loop is the following

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mydata)){
  filename <- paste(mydata$name[i], ".asc")
  print(filename)
  Idascharacter <- as.character(mydata$id[i])
  print(Idascharacter)
}
```